# How to create a relationship in Neo4j across an entire dataset between different labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My situation is as follows. I have a dataset of companies and employess.

Only nodes exists in 2 different labels; person and company. The relationships have not been created. I need to create the relationships across the entire dataset.

```
person object:
name: blah
org_lookup_id: 1234

company object
comp: etc
org_id: 1234
```

I want to create a relationship for the node. For 1 node this is easy.

```
MATCH (a:person  {name: "blah"}),
      (c:company {comp: "etc"})
MERGE (a)-[r:WORKS_FOR]->(b)
```

However, I am trying to cartisean join them and do it across the entire set..

```
MATCH (p:person),(c:company)
WHERE p.org_lookup_id=c.org_id
MERGE (p)-[r:WORKS_AT]->(c)
RETURN type(r)
```

This returns no results...

My goal is to have X amount of relationships created in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query works as expected, there is a Cartesian join between the objects.

```
MATCH (p:person),(d:company)
WHERE p.org_lookup_id=d.org_id
merge (p)-[r:WORKS_FOR]->(d)
RETURN type(r)
```

Comment: It is mysterious why this this should work for you but the original version would not. I had no problem with the original version. By the way: you'd probably get better performance if you create an index on `:person(org_lookup_id)`, as that would allow the planner to use the index to efficiently find all the people who work for each company.

Comment: I definitely agree that it was bizarre. I do not have a reason as they are pretty much identical.  thank you for the advise on the index definition.